# Workflow with MSMQ and Buffered Receive

Tags: wcf, msmq, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, netmsmqbinding

We are building Workflow Foundation service with .NET 4.5 and are attempting to use MSMQ to deliver messages that Workflow Service should process.

We have enabled Allow Buffered Receive in order to have messages wait for Workflow to be able to process them.

However, we've ended up with some weird kind of locks in our message folders (see the pictures).

There is no documentation whatsoever to explain this. What is this? Is it related to WF, WCF, MSMQ? Where to look for solution?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about the locks but I decided to implement my own queuing solution within my workflow  outside of MSMQ due to past issues with MSMQ.  I found the following article that helped me implement a queuing solution using SQL Server [Implementing Message Queues in Relation Databases](http://kejser.org/implementing-message-queues-in-relational-databases/)

Using a variant of this technique, IIS 7.5 AutoStart, WWF bookmarks and Context Based Correlation I was able to implement a persistent queue within my workflow without using MSMQ.  The nature of workflow makes queuing within the workflow very doable.